# Content URI of Alarm DB

Tags: android

What is the content URI of Alarm DB in Froyo(API level 8)?
I am trying with Uri.parse("content://com.android.deskclock/alarm"); which is not working.

Please help me out

Comment: [this][1] is my solution, hope that it's useful for you.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15081573/get-alarm-infomation-and-changing-it-in-android-4-0/27616154#27616154

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Foryo (API 8) try using this URI "content://com.android.alarmclock/alarm".

Answer (score 0):

There is no documented and supported content provider for alarm clock apps in Android.